# Install for @angular/cli not working on Mac

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to setup Angular 2 using "npm install @angular/cli -g "

After the install, the only warning I see is the  UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@^5.0.1, which I then install and reinstall "npm install @angular/cli -g"

No matter what I do, or what version of Node I setup with n, I keep getting the following message when trying to user the "ng" commands:

zsh: command not found: ng

I've been looking around and have not found a solution for this.

Has anyone run into this and have any suggestions?

UPDATE:

It looks like this is not a angular/cli specific issue.

I now see that I get the same message when I try to run "Grunt" and "Ionic" commands on an existing project that was working fine.

zsh: command not found: ionic
zsh: command not found: grunt

Comment: Drop the @ and try it again. If that doesn't work, you may have run `sudo npm install` at some point, if that's the case you'd need to run `sudo npm install -g angular/cli` due to permission issues. You can typically fix that using chown or chmod on your ~/.npm folder.

If *that* doesn't work, uninstall angular/cli and reinstall it.

Comment: Hi Austin, I tried your suggestions, but it didn't work. I now have noticed that on an existing project, where I use grunt, it get's a similar message when trying to run the grunt command: zsh: command not found: grunt. I'm thinking there is more to this than just angular/cli.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most likely, the directory in which the global modules are installed is not in your `$PATH` -- and therefore unknown to your shell.

To fix this issue, we can create a new directory for global node_modules, configure `npm` to use it, and add that directory to your `$PATH`.

```sh
# create a new directory where npm will install packages
$  mkdir ~/.node_modules

# set npm "prefix" config to that directory
$  npm config set prefix '~/.node_modules'

# append a line to your .zshrc instructing it to include that directory in your $PATH, making the executables known to the shell
$ echo 'export PATH=~/.node_modules/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc

# update current shell with new path (not needed for new sessions)
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

Then, first reinstall the latest npm (`npm i -g npm`), followed by the global packages you need (`npm i -g @angular/cli`).

For more on `PATH`, see this definition: http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html

Comment: I tried this solution, but got an error with my `nvm`. Any advice on the work around? `Your user’s .npmrc file (${HOME}/.npmrc)
has a `globalconfig` and/or a `prefix` setting, which are incompatible with nvm.
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v20.11.1 --silent` to unset it.`

Comment: ^ what worked for me was running `npm cache verify` before `nvm install -g @angular/cli` didn't need to add thte prefix or edit the .zshrc file ([solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45658229/4739826))