# How to run ng serve on terminal when using angular console tool?

Tags: angular, angular-console

I'am using [angular console](https://angularconsole.com/) to run and test etc. my app. This working fine. But when I try to run it via terminal without using angular console, it throws the following:  `-bash: ng: command not found`.

I made sure that the **`node_module`** is in installed via **`npm install`** under the specific project, using/installing all the dependencies.

Also when I try to run `ng -v`, I get the same message: `-bash: ng: command not found`. I assume that the global installation of `@angular/cli` is not correct on my machine or something similar.

I have been searching here in SO, and found kind of similar questions but I think my issue seems to be different. Also I'am not 100% sure if it has to do with angular console, but I just ask my self why it works when using `angular console` but not when using the terminal directly?

Any hint how to solve/fix this?

Comment: Seems like problem with your angular-cli installation. Run `which ng` and see if it is installed properly.

Comment: When I run `which ng`, there is no output at all. But I can see that I do have a node_module folder globally and also under the specific project folder. It also has the sub folder: `@angular/cli`. This is kind of strange.

Comment: The global installation seems to be broken. Please install it again using `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

Comment: This is what I thought and I did install a specific version globally using `npm install -g @angular/cli@7.0.6` and it throws: `[fsevents] Success: "/Users/myUserName/node_modules/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" is installed via remote
+ @angular/cli@7.0.6`. And after that, when I run `ng verve`, `ng -v` I get `-bash: ng: command not found` and when I run `which ng`, there is no output at all. I assume something is not working correctly even if it says: `[fsevents] Success:...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng: command not found while creating new project using angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227794/ng-command-not-found-while-creating-new-project-using-angular-cli)

Comment: This is not a duplicated question. It looks like but it's not. Please read my question carefully and check the details. Anyway, I have solved the issue based on this question: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323442/install-for-angular-cli-not-working-on-mac). The answer of Sinan. If there is no answer or hint from your side, please, don't just mark a question as duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved based on the answer in the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323442/install-for-angular-cli-not-working-on-mac)

Solution:

```
# create a new directory where npm will install packages
$  mkdir ~/.node_modules

# set npm "prefix" config to that directory
$  npm config set prefix '~/.node_modules'

# append a line to your .zshrc instructing it to include that directory in your $PATH, making the executables known to the shell
$ echo 'export PATH=~/.node_modules/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc

# update current shell with new path (not needed for new sessions)
$ source ~/.zshrc
```